# Condition for the asymptotic non-zero point estimation of the variance

Tags: probability, variance, estimation, convergence, sample

we know that a condition for a non-zero point estimate of the variance for a finite sample is that there exist at least two integers $i,j$ such that $X_i\neq X_j$. In other words $\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \left(X_i-\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{j=1}^n X_j\right)^2 \neq 0$ if there exist at least two integers $i,j$ such that $X_i\neq X_j$. My question is if this property remains true in the case of infinite sample i.e. is it $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \left(X_i-\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{j=1}^n X_j \right)^2 \neq 0$ if $\exists 
 \ i,j$ such that $X_i \neq X_j$?

Comment: Consider the sample $(X_i) = (1,0,0,\ldots,0,0\ldots).$

Comment: Thank you, in this sample case the variance is $\frac{n(n-1)}{n^3}$ which converges to 0. The property is not true in infinite sample. Can you provide a condition for the variance to be asymptotically non-zero?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "property not true in infinite sample."  This *is* an infinite sample.  You aren't asking for a probabilistic statement: as stated, your question is purely about sequences of numbers.  The variance, btw, is $(n-1)/n^2:$ there's no factor of $n$ in the numerator.

Comment: It sounds like you might be looking for an example of a sequence of random variables for which the chance that the limit is zero is 100%. There are various ways to produce such sequences, modeled after the example I gave.  For instance, add vanishingly small multiples of independent Bernoulli variables to the components of this sequence.

Comment: I just forget to simplify by $n$. My question is; we have a sequence of random variables $(X_1,X_2,........)$ not necessary identically distributed or independents (we know anything about these variables). What is a condition for $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \left(X_i-\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{j=1}^n X_j \right)^2$ to be different from 0? Thank you very much.

Comment: In other words If $\bar{X}_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i$.  I'm looking for a condition that verifies $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \left(X_i-\bar{X}_n\right)^2 \neq 0$?

Comment: One can invent as many conditions as you like.  Asking for us to propose some conditions is just too vague.  It would be more productive for you to tell us the *specific* problem you have.  What do you know about your samples?

Comment: I have constructed 3 estimators using the ML method for a continuous stochastic model that i discretized using the Euler scheme to get a discret sample of random variables . Next, i have calculated the errors of estimation (e.g. $\hat{\alpha}-\alpha$). To prove the strong consistency of these estimators, i successfully prove that the numerators  of the errors converge to zero. Accordingly, to show that the errors converge to zero i need to prove that the denominators (which equal $\frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{i=1}^n (X_i-\bar{X})^2$ in all the errors) does not converge to 0 in infinity.

Comment: In order to not obtain $\frac{0}{0}$  at infinity. I notice that The Euler Maruyama scheme is used to construct a discret sample $(X_1, X_2,\dots,X_n)$ from the continuous stochastic model. The sample is used then to estimate the parameters of the model using the maximum likelihood method. I need to prove that the difference between the estimator of a parameter and its true value converges to 0 in order to prove the strong consistency of this estimator.

Comment: "Obtain 0/0 at infinity" does not make any sense, because there is no "at infinity" in any limit.  All limits concern properties of *finite* portions of a sequence.  Regardless, your comment is so different from what you have posted that you ought to consider modifying the post to focus on the problem you actually have.